# 'On' vs 'at' are there any principles that advise using one instead of the other when expressing the location of something?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

The building is located on the corner of Bank and Butler.

Vs.

The building is located at the corner of Bank and Butler.

Is there any reason why one is more appropriate than the other?

Comment: You will find considerable differences between this type of prepositional use between North America and the UK. Widely discussed before on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the simple context of the OP, the expressions are interchangeable, but all other variables being equal, the intention of entering the building ***on*** the corner of Bank and Butler **might** be the ***practical connection*** that makes ***at*** the corner of Bank and Butler more appropriate.

Examining the etymology of ***[at](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=at&searchmode=none)***

> Old English æt,
>
> from Proto-Germanic *at*
>
> (cognates: Old Norse, Gothic at, Old Frisian et, Old High German az), from PIE *ad- "to, near, at"
>   (cognates: Latin ad "to, toward" Sanskrit adhi "near;" see ad-). Lost in German and Dutch, which use their equivalent of to; in
>   Scandinavian, however, to has been lost and at fills its place.
>
> In choosing between *at church*, *in church*, etc. *at* is properly
>   distinguished from *in* or *on* by **involving some practical connection**; a
>   worshipper is at church; a tourist is in the church.
>
> **Emphasis** mine

A person who works ***at*** the corner of Bank and Butler, might describe the building to a stranger:

> *It's **on** the corner of Bank and Butler*.

He assumes the stranger has **no practical connection** to the building.

If the same stranger were to ask him where he works, he is likely say:

> *I work **at** the corner of Bank and Butler*.

He is communicating his **practical connection** to the place, but he is just as likely to say:

> *I work **at** the building **on** the corner of Bank and Butler*.

In that case, ***at*** the building expresses his practical connection, while ***on*** the corner expresses its generic location.

Answer (score 1):

This is completely observational, (they are basically interchangeable) but...

"At" seems to denote a place you can enter, while "on" is more like outside. That doesn't make perfect sense, but:

"I'll be on the third floor, at the shoe department."

"I'll be at the Empire State Building, on 34th St."

If you're "at the mall", you're *in* a shopping center - if you're "on the mall" you're on open grounds.

(I know there must be a lot of exceptions to this - but, I guess it's a start)

Answer (score 0):

Usually "on" implies placement (as in "upon") whereas "at" is a somewhat less descriptive location word.

Webster says "on" involves contact or close proximity; "at" is "a function word to indicate presence or occurrence in, on, or near."